# Android - Changed java version and now changed back app won't run

Tags: java, android

I wanted to use a switch function in my app from a string. When I did that eclipse said I had to upgrade to java 1.7 which stupidly I let it do. It then told me to use the Android Fix Project to fix it. Which I did and subsequently it reverted back to 1.5. Good (I thought)

Now my app wont run :(

Heres the structure of the app.

[image]

Heres the errors:
The main bit:

```
10-04 13:39:04.974: D/AndroidRuntime(11532): Shutting down VM
10-04 13:39:04.974: W/dalvikvm(11532): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5c1f8)
10-04 13:39:04.974: E/AndroidRuntime(11532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 13:39:04.974: E/AndroidRuntime(11532): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.Globals.Global: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.Globals.Global
10-04 13:39:04.974: E/AndroidRuntime(11532):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
```

The full log can be found at: http://pastebin.com/rMLqkDc2

Here's my android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.directenquiries.assessment.tool"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:name=".Globals.Global"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_page" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainPage"
            android:label="Select Item" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".JobSheet"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_job_sheet" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationListView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_location_list_view" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm not at a bit of a loss what to do

Comment: Also set your project's Java complier compliance to 1.6

Comment: Unfortunately i've tried both of them. Same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay So heres what happened and how I fixed it. The android 'fix' set it back to 1.5 but I apparently was at 1.6. I changed it back to 1.6, did a clean, didn't work. Uninstalled it from the phone and cleaned again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project and then goto build path and then Configure Build Path ...

In the JavaCompiler --- > update the Java Compiler to 1.7

Comment: Thanks, but the java version is now correct. It just seems to have changed something else in the app somewhere when I did it

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project > Properties > Then click on "Java Compiler" on the left panel.
Here you can change the java version used to compile your project